# Comma Seperator value in PHP MYSQL and redirecting users

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table and query like this

## my_table

```
    book_id     values

    1           1,2,3
    2           1,2,4
```

## Code

```
    <?php 
    $my_value = "1";
    $get_page_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table where values IN($my_value)");
    ?>
```

So, if the $my_value is inside the table, then take the user to welcome.php page else take them to error.php page.

How can I do that?

Please help me

## EDIT

My above sample code is not working.. help me out please

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your query, because you are searching for `1` in the set stored in the table, not the other way around. After changing your query you can use the way provided in the other answers, we end up with this code:

```
<?php 
$my_value = "1";
$get_page_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE
                               FIND_IN_SET('$my_value' , values)>0");

if(mysql_num_rows($get_page_query)>0){
   //welcome page 
}
?>
```

**Sidenote 1: as the comment on your question states, your table structure is bad, you should try normalizing your data.**

**Sidenote 2: you shouldn't still be using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated, check out [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)**

Comment: noted with thanks, your code worked well. !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($get_page_query)>0){
  header('Location: welcome.php');
  /* Make sure that code below does not get executed when redirected. */
  exit; 
} else {
   header('Location: error.php');
  /* Make sure that code below does not get executed when redirected. */
  exit;
}
```

Comment: please check my code again. my code is bad one. i need code from someone so that it will help me out –

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysql_num_rows`, try this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($get_page_query)) {
    header('Location:welcome.php');
} else {
    header('Location:error.php');
}
```

Comment: please check my code again. my code is bad one. i need code from someone so that it will help me out

Answer (score 1):

error in your table field name. you are using `values` as table field name. which is a keyword in MySql So please change your table field name.

book_id     `book_value`

```
1           1,2,3
2           1,2,4
```